# Запуск приложения на Flutter на физическом устройстве Apple (iOs 14+)

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть такая проблема: нужно запустить приложение на физическом устройстве iOS 14+, так как в приложении  используется АПИ и есть get-запросы на сервер, то при первой попытке в стэктрейсе ошибка, что

```
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(101)] Failed to register observatory port with mDNS with error -65555.
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(103)] On iOS 14+, local network broadcast in apps need to be declared in the app's Info.plist. Debug and profile Flutter apps and modules host VM services on the local network to support debugging features such as hot reload and DevTools. To make your Flutter app or module attachable and debuggable, add a '_dartobservatory._tcp' value to the 'NSBonjourServices' key in your Info.plist for the Debug/Profile configurations. For more information, see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions
```

Перешел по всем ссылкам, что указаны в стэктрейсе, сделал все, что написано самим flutter.dev, добавил следующие строчки кода в Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>

<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_dartobservatory._tcp</string>
</array>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Почему добавляю первую строчку в Info.plist? Потому что это же приложение у меня уже запускалось и нормально работает на Андроид-устройствах (любых, тестировал и на самых слабых и на флагманах), ругалось только на Bad State Http. Здесь же  решил, что в iOs принцип такой же.

Также читал, что  Bad State Http ругается, когда используешь не https, а http. В моем АПИ именно http, сделать с этим ничего нельзя, к сожалению.

Так вот после всех танцев с бубнами и включением самой Local Network на физическом устройстве, я все равно получаю бесконечную загрузку и никакого ответа. Хотя все сделал по официальным докам.

Так как с iOS работаю впервые, то не знаю как правильно решать эту задачу. Есть ли какие-нибудь подсказки по этому поводу? Уже второй день сижу, никак не могу заставить собраться готовой код на физическом устройстве.

Comment: > `ругалось только на Bad State Http`, приложите полную ошибку.

Comment: @MiT `Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: ` , но я не думаю, что это чем-то поможет. Ответ на эту ошибку существует уже давно и про него написана даже статья, на android решается вот так: https://fluttercorner.com/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform-in-a-flutter/  и вот ответ со стэковера: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform для iOs с моими спеками этого недостаточно. Сама же flutter-team предупреждает что все манипуляции что описаны у них в доке могут привести к отказу со стороны

Comment: @MiT к отказу со стороны эпп стор и придется объяснять, почему я добавил это строчку. Вот тут описано, собственно, по этой доке я и делал: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions

Comment: не думали подключить ssl на сервере? Это будет куда легче и надёжнее. Тем более есть возможность подключить бесплатный, например: https://letsencrypt.org/ru/

Comment: @MiT предлагал такое решение, ведущий разраб не согласен, да и сами разрабы АПИ против :( не знаю даже, что делать

Comment: какие у них аргументы против ssl?

Comment: проблема решилась, надо было просто включить мобильный интернет на телефоне и отключить корпоративный вай-фай, почему-то ругался именно на него. Как только отключил вай-фай все заработало